# Excel VBA - "Run-time error 13: Type mismatch" when cell range is more than 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA so that a click of a button will save the worksheet as a particular name (which is linked to a certain cell), however, I want it to canel the save if certain cells are blank.

When doing the code for 1 cell it works fine, however, when I put a range of cells, it gives me a "Run-time error 13: Type mismatch" error.

My code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

IF Sheets("Event").range("C4:C24").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Please fill in column C"

Else


Dim IntialName As String
Dim fileSaveName As Variant
InitialName = range("c7")
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
    fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

  If fileSaveName <> "False" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs (fileSaveName)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: `Range.Value` yields that value when it's one cell. If it's multiple cells, what you get is a 2D `Variant` array. You can't compare a 2D `Variant` array with anything - you need to iterate the individual cells and compare each one.

Answer (score 2):

`Range(...)` without property specifying returns its default property `.Value`.

If a range contains 1 cell, `.Value` returns scalar value.

If a range contains more than 1 cell, `.Value` returns 2-dimentional array of `Variant`. Of course it cannot be assigned into a `String` type variable or compared with string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Mathieu Guindon and @Akina.

I've change my script as follows and now it's working:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim myrange As range
Set myrange = Worksheets("Event").range("C4:C24")


If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myrange) < _
myrange.Cells.Count Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Cells in column C must not be empty."

Else



Dim IntialName As String
Dim fileSaveName As Variant
InitialName = range("c7")
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, _
    fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

  If fileSaveName <> "False" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs (fileSaveName)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If



End If
End Sub
```